# Why does my Java class fail to compile when compiled from inside the package directory?

Tags: java, package, compilation

I have made a directory called "middle" and inside it another directory called "tier" and inside the "tier" directory are OrderManager.java which is an interface and OrderManagerImpl.java having its implementation.

The problem is when I try to compile OrderManagerImpl.java from outside the package middle.tier it compiles but when I do the same inside the package it gives me the following error:

```
OrderManagerImpl.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol: class OrderManager
public class OrderManagerImpl extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject implements OrderManager{
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the compiler expects to find your class inside the proper folder: ./middle/tier . When you try to compile inside the package, the compiler search for your class in ./middle/tier/middle/tier

Comment: i thought that compiler serches the classpath which includes the current directory

Comment: Yes, so it will search the current directory for middle.tier.OrderManager, which means it looks for a directory called "middle" with a subdirectory called "tier" - all *under* the current directory.